# Tensorflow with Cuda, libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object. eclipse (Liclipse)

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, cuda, tensorflow, cudnn

When I import tensorflow in Liclipse I get the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/workspace/project", line 13, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have correctly installed tensorflow and cuda and both work fine from the terminal.
Tensorflow was installed via pip and I am using cuda 7.5 and cuDNN v4 and 
I am using ubuntu 14.04.
The cuda samples compile and run perfectly as does tensorflow outside of Liclipse.

I have added cuda to both my path and LD_LIBRARY_PATH in .bashrc:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I have the Liclipse python interpreter set up as:
/usr/bin/python-2.7

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have tried explicitly adding '/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64' to my python path as well as manually adding it to the liclipse interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, I had the same problem using Python 3 + PyDev + Eclipse (which I believe might be similar to Liclipse in this respect); what helped in my case was to add the cuda lib folder to my `PYTHONPATH` when running the IDE, e.g.,

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64 ./myEclipseFolder/eclipse
```

That made PyDev offer me the cuda lib folder for inclusion when setting up the Python interpreter, and then my tensorflow scripts worked.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but a work around. I'm simply running my scripts from the terminal. Its a pain for debugging but I am still unable to get TF to work with Liclipse.