# Tensorflow GPU Python 3.5. Eclipse has error: ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file:

Tags: eclipse, tensorflow, gpu

I installed Tensorflow GPU v1.0 on Python 3.5 Anaconda envrionment. All seems fine. I can run Juputer notebook and in terminal, the following lines. It tells GPU is running fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))



====Output
Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Mar  6 2017, 11:58:13) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened    CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
>>> sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))


…

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 1 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 1:   Y Y 
…
```

But, in Eclipse, I set environment by select Ananconda/env//bin/python. Above 2 GPU validation lines gives error:

ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried Tensorflow CPU in another Anaconda environment, Jupyter, terminal, Eclipse, all GOOD!

What's missing in Eclipse for tensorflow GPU?  Any extra step to make Eclipse work for Tensoflow GPU v1.0.

========Error Message========

```
File "/home/<username>/anaconda3/envs/dl-conda-py35/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "/home/<username>/anaconda3/envs/dl-conda-py35/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But the file: libcudart.so.8.0 exist.

```
$ls /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0
```

I Setup Eclipse Python interpreter same way as Tensorflow CPU (CPU has no problem). But GPU tensorflow has problem.

Comment: have you installed CUDA version 8? If so all your libs should live in `/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcuda*`, you may have to run ldconfig to update the shared library cache (so that tensorflow can find it)

Comment: cuda8,cudnn5 installed. I checked installation, it looks fine. I can run some tensorflow projects. Some projects do not run on tensorflow gpu version, but those run fine on tensorflow cpu. I know gpu version seems not stable. it's ok with me. I am trying to figure out why Eclipse not work for tensorflow gpu v1.0, and give me the error.

Comment: run `ls /usr/local/cuda/lib64/`  What do you get? Then make & run a couple of the cuda8 samples @ `/usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities` (that will use libcudart) and make sure they run. If they don't run, your installation is not correct (and Eclipse will not find it).

Comment: ls /usr/local/cuda/lib64/. libcudart.so is found. /usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/bandwidthTest$ ./bandwidthTest. It runs ok. Eclipse does not work, only Tensorflow GPU v1.0, Python3.5. For Tensorflow CPU, Eclipse ok for me.

Comment: Added detailed error message to original post.

Answer (score 1):

interestingly, I followed ruoho ruotsi instructions. When I start eclipse with sudo ./yourEclipse/eclipse, it can't still find cuda, but without sudo,it can.

update: 
if I use sudo to launch eclipse, I have to add LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/local/cuda/lib64 in eclipse by setting Run configurations -> environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that this may related to sudo, which "has a default policy of resetting the Environment and setting a secure path (this behavior is defined in /etc/sudoers)": https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#sudo_caveat

Answer (score 0):

You have a similar problem to this [cuda7.5 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37593427/tensorflow-with-cuda-libcudart-so-7-5-cannot-open-shared-object-eclipse-licl). Have a quick glance.

I recommend adding the CUDA lib folder to your PYTHONPATH when running the IDE.

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64 ./myEclipseFolder/eclipse
```

In a nutshell, because you can work from the command line but not from the Eclipse IDE, you have to configure the Eclipse python interpreter correctly and point it to the correct CUDA lib & bin paths. This is not required for TensorFlow CPU, which doesn't rely on `libcudart.so` Good luck!

*Update* -- added Liclipse/PyDev screenshot:[image]

*Update 2*: Running the code above this is the message I get, TF GPU is working: [image]

Comment: Thank you for reply. How to add it? I only know .project file under project workspace. 1) I tried manually add '/usr/local/cuda/lib64' to PyDev-Interpreter/Grammar configuration-> python interpreter : bottom section : Libraries (PYTHONPATH). 2) Add '/usr/local/cuda/lib64' PyDev-PYTHONPATH:External Library. But, both do not work.

Comment: I added a screenshot ... does that match what you're doing? I didn't see a Grammar configuration in my setup

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I did and I see same configuration on my machine as the screen shot. Not work. I reboot machine, still not work. Is this work for you?

Comment: I posted a screen shot of what my Eclipse looks like running your commands, TF GPU is working ...opens the GPU and reports device is ready.  Can you run `pip freeze | grep tensorflow` ... I show: `tensorflow-gpu==1.0.0`

Comment: pip freeze | grep tensorflow shows: tensorflow-gpu==1.0.0 on my PC. But Eclipse does not working for me. Your screenshot shows GPU working. Let me dig more.  Really appreciate your screenshot (I think it's my problem, and it should work). If switching to a CPU Tensoflow, it work immediately for me.

Comment: Can you share how you installed tensorflow gpu and its environment? I created anaconda3 environment and 'pip3 install tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl', which is build on my PC by specifying cuda:8.0 cudnn:5, and my gtx computability: 6.1. For tensorflow cpu, I 'conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow' (GPU not available for this command). I did not use virtualenv. Interesting, for tensorflow gpu environment: 'conda list' does not show 'tensorflow-gpu', only pip freeze show 'tensorflow-gpu 1.0'. For cpu environment, 'conda list' and 'pip freeze' shows 'tensorflow 1.0'.

Comment: Hi there, I use the directions here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingNativePip to install TF-GPU using my anaconda3  pip. `$ pip install tensorflow-gpu`. I do not use virtual env and running `conda list shows`: 
`tensorflow-gpu            1.0.0                     <pip>`

Comment: I think based on your last comment & @Zheng Yuan's comment, i would (1) retry installing TF-GPU *WITHOUT* an anaconda environment. So just use pip to give it to anaconda3 everywhere. (2) Run Eclipse IDE *WITHOUT* using `sudo ./Eclipse` to launch.

Comment: If this has resolved your problem please mark as answered. Cheers.

Comment: Still not yet. I am still trying to figure out. May be I need to reinstall on the new virtualenv or anaconda env.

Comment: can you NOT use an anaconda env?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think that the first thing would be running it from the command line... after that, my suggestion is starting Eclipse from that same shell and then checking if all environment variables when you launch it match the ones from the shell.

As a note, the PYTHONPATH is a special variable in PyDev made up from the files you add in the interpreter and in source folders in projects, so, to check the PYTHONPATH my suggestion is creating a program with:

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path)))
```

and run that from the command line and from inside Eclipse to compare what may be different (and fix the configuration on PyDev accordingly).

Comment: I tried. Eclipse, terminal, notebook, all output same env. But, Eclipse still does not work. In Eclipse, I added /usr/local/cuda/lib64 to 'Libraries' when setting up Interpreter. BTW, This is new Anaconda env, 'conda list' shows tensorflow-gpu 1.0.1

Comment: 1) Created virtualenv python3.5, tensorflow GPU. Eclipse has same problem, as Anaconda env. Terminal work, Eclipse not work. 2) Tried "Fabio Zadrozny" suggested 2 line script. Terminal and Eclipse output are the same, and Eclipse has extra: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
/usr/local/cuda/lib64, which is added by me, hoping Eclipse use the directory to solve "ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". STILL NOT work.

Comment: Try to do the following: create virtualenv, activate it, launch eclipse from that same shell (with the virtualenv activated) and check if it works.

Comment: Fabio, thank your for replay. How to start eclipse from terminal. I have: ~/eclipse/jee-neon/eclipse$ ls
configuration  dropins  eclipse  eclipse.ini  icon.xpm  plugins  readme

Comment: Just execute ./eclipse